# Specifically matching an object in html5 that runs a CS project in Khan Academy

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I made a button that downloads your khan Academy projects. It gets html of each project and tries to find,

(Now I just need to find) a certain javascript object/JSON inside of the html. I just need to match it using regex in javascript.
But the problem is it keeps on changing as developers change the code all the time.

I need regex that will always match it.
It currently looks like this:

```
window["./javascript/tutorial-scratchpad-package/scratchpad-page-entry.js"] = {...
More JSON here
```

A project link is here:
https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/sounds/5794961426055168

I've tried matching it different ways but it keeps on changing.

```
function extractCode(str)
{
    var test = "$LAB.queueWait(function() {window[\"./javascript/tutorial-scratchpad-package/scratchpad-page-entry.js\"] = ";
    var index = str.indexOf(test) + test.length;
    return str.substring(index, str.indexOf("</script>", index)).slice(0, -2);
}
```

Comment: This feels like a good question, not one that could get voted down. I never knew such thing as a "dumb question" until now.

Comment: Also I think regexr is also pretty handy.

Comment: https://regexr.com